# How can I send the multipart file type request in flutter with specific requirements?

Tags: spring, flutter, dart, http, multipart

[Request which I need to send with post method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUIlw.jpg)

```
multipartFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
  'supportDocuments', item.files.single.bytes!,
      contentType: MediaType('application', 'pdf'));
      request.files.add(multipartFile);

request.headers.addAll(headers);
request.fields["processRequestDto"] = jsonEncode(docRefDto);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/dio : Use dio package to simply send form data requests.